# Need a server to monitor the outflow of request

Tags: server

I am trying to open a small office, with the machine support of five. I would like to setup a proxy server to share the broadband connection in the ‎office and also to restrict the access to certain social media websites. How am I supposed to go about. Kindly note that I cannot have an extravagant expenditure as the financial resources are limited. An early reply would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use squid proxy server. Configure your gateway router to route all outbound traffic from your office through the squid proxy server.

This would afford you the following advantages:

- caching of web pages
- fine control of what websites and external ip addresses can or cannot be connected to
- optional whitelist or blacklist models for allowing access to external web sites / ip addresses
- configurable level of logging for what traffic is passing through the proxy server

Here is a link to the squid wiki to get you started:
[ConfigExamples - Squid Web Proxy Wiki](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples)

Edit - response to question about using this on Ubuntu Server:
Here is a link to Ubuntu Server Guide -

[Ubuntu 14.04 Server Guide PDF](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf)

I highly recommend that you download and keep handy this great pdf. It will help you get started on a huge variety of server-related projects and tasks on Ubuntu Server. See chapter 11, Section 3 for squid. Once you get started doing something from the Server Guide, consult official documentation for whatever type of server software you are utilizing, squid in this case.